# Problem with arrows and subgraphs in Mermaid

Tags: mermaid

I am trying to draw a flow diagram using Mermaid using a subgraph. The subgraph has LR (left to right) flow and it's supposed to show two data sources being loaded into SQL. The main graph has direction TD (top down). I cannot get one of the arrows to show up in the sub-diagram - the leftwards-pointing arrow is missing. Here is the code:

```
flowchart TD

A((START)) -- Routes process --> LOAD

subgraph LOAD
  direction LR
  DB1[(OAG\ndata)] --CSV\nfile--> L
  L[SQL] <--CSV\nfile--- DB2
  DB2[(Routes\ndata)]
end

LOAD --> E((END))
```

I have been using https://mermaid.live/ as my Mermaid editor and renderer, and using https://mermaid.js.org/intro/ as documentation. My Mermaid document and the output look like this:

[image: Mermaid flow diagram with missing arrow]

Any sugestions are welcome! Normally I use Visio and I only discovered Mermaid last week and it's a lot easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

It's currently not possible, writing arrows from right to left is not supported, there are open issues on the Mermaid repository to request that functionality, but they've been there for years, I guess there's little chance of this ever being implemented...

Well, you cannot write `A <-- B`, you have to write `B --> A`, which is logically the same.

So in your case :

```
flowchart TD

A((START)) -- Routes process --> LOAD

subgraph LOAD
  direction LR
  DB1[(OAG\ndata)] --CSV\nfile--> L
  DB2 --CSV\nfile--> L[SQL]
  DB2[(Routes\ndata)]
end

LOAD --> E((END))
```

[image]

But as you see it breaks the horizontal layout...

The best I had achieved is to create a hidden line to force the horizontal layout :

```
flowchart TD

A((START)) -- Routes process --> LOAD

subgraph LOAD
  direction LR
  DB1[(OAG\ndata)] --CSV\nfile--> L
  DB2 --CSV\nfile--> L[SQL]
  DB2[(Routes\ndata)]
  L --- DB2
end

LOAD --> E((END))

linkStyle 3 stroke: transparent
```

[image]

A more symmetrical version, with 2 hidden lines :

```
flowchart TD

A((START)) -- Routes process --> LOAD

subgraph LOAD
  direction LR
  DB1[(OAG\ndata)] --CSV\nfile--> L
  DB2 --CSV\nfile--> L[SQL]
  DB2[(Routes\ndata)]
  DB1 --- L
  L --- DB2
end

LOAD --> E((END))

linkStyle 3 stroke: transparent
linkStyle 4 stroke: transparent
```

[image]

(you can also use `display: none` or `stroke-width: 0` to hide the lines)

There are other solutions that involve creating your own CSS classes outside mermaid, to be used to hide arrow heads for example, but these won't necessarily be compatible everywhere, see https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid/issues/1236 if you want to give a try.